# SharePoint Content Query Webpart, display results in two columns

Tags: sharepoint, cqwp

Is there any good reference to change Content Query Webpart formatting. I would like to display results in two columns for a specific CQWP without changing the XSL file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by using SPServices, JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change XSLT.
see e.g.: 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/1484df2b-0fb9-4b58-b833-a75019db88c7/content-query-display-multiple-columns

Please check the below link

http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/01/21/displaying-results-in-multiple-columns-using-the-content-query-web-part/

Other option is you ca use Dataview webpart to show the list details from one site to other site

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/08/12/sharepoint-2013-add-dataview-webpart-with-sharepoint-designer-2013/

http://sharepointgeorge.com/2009/display-sharepoint-list-site-data-view-web-part/